# How to make the icon dynamically active using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***HTML***

```
 <div class="zoom py-3">
    <i nz-icon nzType="minus" (click)="zoomToggle(false)" nzTheme="outline"></i><br>
    <i nz-icon nzType="plus" (click)="zoomToggle(true)" nzTheme="outline"></i><br>
    <i nz-icon nzType="drag" [class.active]="zoomDrag" (click)="toggleZoomDrag()" nzTheme="outline"></i>
    <i nz-icon nzType="undo" (click)="zoomToggle(null, true)" nzTheme="outline"></i>
    <br><i nz-icon nzType="edit" [class.active]="editing" (click)="toggleEditing()" nzTheme="outline"></i>
  </div>
```

***TS***

```
editing = false;
zoomDrag = false

toogleZoomDrag() {
 this.zoomDrag = !zoomDrag;
}

zoomToggle() {
 this.editing = !editing;
}
```

the problem here is when I click the `icon move` it will be active and then when I click the `icon edit` it should remove the active on `icon move`.

Example:

[image]

I click the icon move then it will active, then when I click the editing.

[image]

the icon move will remove the active, then the editing will be active. then when I click the move icon while its editing it should be active as same the second photo. but when I click the editing both will be inactive. which it should be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
editing = false;
zoomDrag = false

toogleZoomDrag() {
 this.zoomDrag = !zoomDrag;
 this.editing = false;
}

zoomToggle() {
 this.editing = !editing;
 this.zoomDrag = false;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. For future readers, it's far more interesting to see explained why this answers the question. And answers with explanations tend to have better acceptance.